# How to pass a character device to something expecting a named pipe

Tags: pipe, devices

Is it possible to convert a special file corresponding to a character device into a pipe?

Specifically if I had an embedded device connected to a linux system via USB, and the device could send/receive 9P commands down the serial link, would it be possible to get [v9fs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/9p.txt) to mount it as a filesystem?
V9fs normally connects to a remote system over a TCP socket but it has the option to use a "a named pipe mount point" or a pair of FDs.
I've done some reading but I haven't tried anything practical yet as I was hoping someone could comment on whether it's feasible or not before I start.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the 9p driver, but it looks like `unix` is for a unix domain socket, rather than a named FIFO. I don't see why you couldn't have the driver read and write to the character device using the `fd` transport though.

Comment: Looks like something `socat` should be able to help you achieve.

Comment: Thanks both. I'll investigate `socat` and/or the fd option